# How do the hand size rules interact with Share Your Nuts?

Tags: nuts

In the game of [Nuts](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/96188/nuts) the rules state:

```
Drawing Cards
Whenever you play a card, whether on your turn or out of
turn, immediately draw a card from the deck.  You should
always have five cards in your hand.
```

There is an Antics card called 'Share Your Nuts' that reads:

```
Pass one card from your hand to the
player on your left, chosen at random.
```

**Do the hand size rules make the person playing the card draw up to five cards and force the player on the left to discard down to five?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes to both. You quoted the answer **You should always have five cards in your hand.** You would draw a card to bring your hand size back to 5, and your opponent would have to discard a card to bring their hand back down to 5.